# Batch file to execute WSL bash.exe with -c flag

Tags: windows, batch-file

What's the equivalent to a shortcut with

```
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "sh /home/rwx/.wsl_shortcuts/terminal.sh"
```

to start it with a Batch file?

## What I tried

```
start "" "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" "sh /home/rwx/.wsl_shortcuts/terminal.sh"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
start "" "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" -c "sh /home/rwx/.wsl_shortcuts/terminal.sh"
```

Did the Job...

Comment: For me `"%SYSTEMROOT%\Sysnative\bash.exe"` instead of `"C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe"` worked.